# UIview animatewithDuration does not works in swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uiview, jquery-animate

This seems to be a very weird issue. I have a small image view in storyBoard and have added tap gesture to it. On the action of gesture I am trying to add a different image view.

Objective C code-

```
-(void)tapImage{
    bigImageView = [[UIImageView alloc]init];
    [bigImageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"main.png"]];

    [bigImageView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50)];
    [self.view addSubview:bigImageView];


    [UIView animateWithDuration:2.0 delay:2.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                     animations:^(void) {

                         [bigImageView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];                         //Leave it empty
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){

                         // Your code goes here

                     }];

}
```

Works totally fine.

Swift Code -

```
func imageTapped()
{
    println("Tapped on Image")

    bigImageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50))
    bigImageView.image = UIImage(named: "main")
    self.view.addSubview(self.bigImageView)


    UIView.animateWithDuration(2.0, delay: 2.0, options:UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseInOut, animations: { () -> Void in
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            self.bigImageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 500))
        }

    }) { (completed:Bool) -> Void in

    }
}
```

Does not work. I don't know where am I wrong. :(

UPDATE -

First I change the frame with "bigimageview.frame" so now it was displaying image view in gesture tap. But without animation.

So I removed dipatch on main  thread and it was animating.

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(0.4, delay: 0.0, options:UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseInOut, animations: { () -> Void in

//            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                self.bigImageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 500)
//            }

            }) { (completed:Bool) -> Void in

        } }
```

But Still question remains why it happened. Are we not suppose to put UI changes on main thread inside closure/block? Some one please explain.

Comment: u r not setting frame properly...follow @Ashish.p's answer

Comment: You are creating a new instance of UIImageView in swift rather, you should be changing the frames only.

Comment: @iphonic agree: new instance of `UIImageView`  with empty image data.

Answer (score 0):

Might be your delay and animation time is same so try this

```
func imageTapped() {
    print("Tapped on Image")

    bigImageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 50, height: 50))
    bigImageView.image = UIImage(named: "main")
    self.view.addSubview(self.bigImageView)


    UIView.animate(withDuration: 2.0, delay: 1.0, options:UIView.AnimationOptions.curveEaseInOut, animations: { () -> Void in
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.bigImageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 320, height: 500))
        }
    }) { (completed:Bool) -> Void in

    }
}
```

Comment: @TusharLimaye Try to animate in viewDidLayoutSubviews and viewDidAppear

Comment: @ParthAdroja Your answer not resolved. Still create new instance of `UIImageView` with no image data.

Answer (score 0):

`viewDidLoad()` is not the ideal place where you should animate views.  `viewDidAppear()` method may works.

Comment: No it is not the issue of viewDidLoad or viewDidAppear. If so it should not work in objective c. Still tried and no success.

Answer (score 0):

**Replace this code**

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(2.0, delay: 1.0, options:UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseInOut, animations: { () -> Void in
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            self.bigImageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 500))
        }

    }) { (completed:Bool) -> Void in

    } }
```

**with**

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(2.0, delay: 1.0, options:UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseInOut, animations: { () -> Void in
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {

            bigImageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 500)
        }

    }) { (completed:Bool) -> Void in

    } }
```

Comment: Ok That great. Atleast my bigImageview is visible but still no animation in it.

Comment: ok. is there any reason for using dispatch_async in animation block?

Comment: Please look at the updated code. 
I have removed dispatch and everything works fine. 
So do we not use UI code on main thread in case of animation? If yes why not?

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing to be gained by trying to use dispatch_async().
The way animations work you simply set the attributes in the specified animation block; the values are, in fact, set immediately and iOS uses the GPU where possible to animate the transition.
If you run the block of code on a different thread it will be outside the scope of the animation and hence simply have an immediate effect.

Answer (score 0):

AnimationWithDuration block takes all of its data(duration, options etc). Your dispatching block simply iterates separately. Thats why its not animating. Reason is simple: everything inside dispatch block iterates separately of other code because of stack system. Frame stopped, dispatch putted to stack, executed, and when it gets back to animation: hop, its already has final value and no animations needed.